# Understanding complex chaining in transition.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys i am new to JS and Jquery in general and i was just going through the source of transition.js and came across the following code :

```
if ($(e.target).is(this)) return e.handleObj.handler.apply(this, arguments)
```

now i understand how the return statement works , i also understand objects in JS(well not entirely , but yeah i get the idea). now i also understand how apply works in js . but still the below line :

```
return e.handleObj.handler.apply(this, arguments)
```

makes very little practical sense to me .

can somebody really break it down and explain it to me ??

`handleObj` - i don't see that anywhere in the plugin ? where is that coming from , its very difficult to understand whats going on on that line .

that perticular line can be found on [git](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/transition.js#L54) too.

Thank you.

Comment: e is the event object. It's part of JavaScript, not a plugin. Similarly, apply is a native JS function.

Answer (score 1):

It is inbuilt object for jQuery event.

> Many of the special event hook functions below are passed a handleObj object that provides more information about the event, how it was attached, and its current state. This object and its contents should be treated as read-only data, and only the properties below are documented for use by special event handlers.

More info on [handleObj](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/#the-handleobj-object) page. There is official description on that link.

Comment: thanks , good referance , however the document is kind of has heavy vocabulary .. anything more beginner friendly (I am aware this is not a beginner topic ) , if you can back up your answer with a few more solid links , i'll give you +15 more browny points ! . Thanks .